# Etymologic origins of "Maimouna"

Tags: passover, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, etymology, chagim-holidays, isru-chag

> Maimouna, the day after Pesach, is probably the most well-known of the
>   isru chag traditions. It originated with the Jews of North Africa, and
>   these days Israelis honour it by making barbecues. There are various
>   explanations for the meaning and origin of the holiday. A messianic hint can be glimpsed in the etymological explanation that sees t**he phrase as a 
>   corruption of “ma’amin ana” – “I believe”. This is a consolatory
>   greeting suggesting that although the Messiah has not, as anticipated,
>   actually arrived this Pesach, we remain hopeful.**

(from here: http://www.masorti.org.uk/newsblog/newsblog/news-single/article/pesach-2.html#.WBGoIC4pBxs).

I find this explanation of the origin of "Maimouna" oddly moving. Is there  evidence that it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia in hebrew](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94)

First hypothesis, from Maymun in arabic, which is chance, luck.

Second hypothesis, the lucky rich woman, who is the kalla, because there was a Minhag to allow marriages at Isru Chag Hapessach.

Third hypothesis, yahrzeit of Rabbi Maimon, the father of Maimonides.

**Fourth hypothesis, alluded in the OP, from Emuna in hebrew, because of a statement in Talmud which said that Jews were delivered in Nissan and would be delivered in Nissan.**

Comment: The OP asked for evidence for a particular view. This post does not cite any evidence for it.

Comment: @mevaqesh, though very weak, a Wikipedia article per se is *some* evidence.

Comment: @msh210 I think not. Its just states that some think this. If God Almighty told me that there are those that think this, that still wouldn't provide a shred of evidence.